# How do I prevent my rails created form from allowing more than 1 radio button to be picked?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason when executing this code, the radio buttons that get created aren't mutually exclusive in getting picked. How do I make it so that users can only pick 1 radio button? This code is essentially going through a variety of addresses and allowing a user to pick an address for their order.

```
<div class="select-address select-address-row" style="display:none">
  <% @order.user.addresses.each do |address, index| %>
    <%= form_for @order, remote: true, :html => { :id => 'address-form-'+address.id.to_s} do |a| %>
      <div class="col-xs-4 select-address-col">
        <div class="enterprise-buy-address-box address-<%= address.id %>">
          <%= address.shipping_name %><br>
          <%= address.line_1 %><br>
          <%= address.city %>, <%= address.state %> <%= address.zipcode %><br>
          <% isDefault = address.shipping_name == @defaultAddress.shipping_name ? true : false %>
          <%= a.radio_button :pickedAddress, 'Address', :checked => isDefault %>
          <%= label :pickedAddress, '' %>
          <div class="submit-address">
            <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-xs btn-default address-custom-button-select address-"+address.id.to_s+"-button") do %>
              select
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= a.hidden_field :address_id, :value => address.id %>
    <% end %>
    <script>
      $('.address-<%=address.id%>-button').click(function() {
        $('.default-address').empty();
        var selectedAddress = $('.address-<%=address.id%>').clone();
        selectedAddress.find('.submit-address').remove();
        $('.default-address').append(selectedAddress);
        $('default-address').addClass("enterprise-buy-address-box");
        $('.default-address').show();
        $('.select-address').toggle();
        $('.change-address-link').toggle();
      });
    </script>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: In order for radio buttons to be exclusive they must have the same name attribute

Comment: @ilanberci And they must belong to the same `form` element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form_for` tag is inside of the loop for the addresses. Even if the `name` attribute is the same for all of your `input type="radio"` elements, they will not be mutually exclusive across different form elements. Move your `form_for` tag outside of the loop so that the radio inputs belong to the same form.

See the following snippet for demonstration:

```html
<p>These won't work</p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</form>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</form>

<p>These do work</p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="bar">
  <input type="radio" name="bar">
</form>
```